# android textview not aligning side by side

Tags: android

I have 4 textviews as -

```
Departure       Timinghello
 hello          Time
45 sec          
                9
```

As you see -

1) In `Departure hello`, 'h' does not start below 'D'. It starts after 1 space.

2) '9' is not in line with '45 sec'

How do I achieve this?

Comment: please post your code and the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this kind of a layout (repeat the inner LinearLayout for each row):

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    >

    <TextLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weight="1"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="Departure"
    />

    <TextLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weight="1"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="TimingHello"
    />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Do not forget the layout_width as 0dp or you will get garbage.

Also best for this kind of a layout would be to use:

```
TableLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    Do this every Row Textview

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/setcancel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/top_color"
            android:text="text"
           />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/setBtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/top_color"
            android:text="txt2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` in the TextView or 
`android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Answer (score -4):

Done these by the help of linearlayout with weights.

First take LinearLayout Vertical which having two Horizontal LinearLayout and both horizontal LinearLayout having two textview with same weight.

Comment: has nothing to do with Layout. It is whitespaces inside TextView itself